# Makefile undefined command when changing order

Tags: php, makefile

I am trying to change the order of the commands in a Makefile.

I need to run the php artisan command before the 2 additional Makefile commands (`dependencies`, `gulp`). `make build` works fine, but `make build2` gives me a `make: dependencies: Command not found` error. I tried on the same line and also on their own line. Thanks.

```
.PHONY: all dependencies gulp build build2

all: dependencies gulp

dependencies:
    ./fetch-dependencies.sh

gulp:
    gulp --production
    NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress

build: dependencies gulp
    php artisan custom:command2 --arg='myarg'

build2:
    php artisan custom:command2 --arg='myarg'
    dependencies 
    gulp
```

Comment: Makefile targets are not functions that can be called.  You can express dependencies (that's what `foo: bar` means), but you can't call them like thta.

Answer (score 1):

You can try add extra rule for artisan

For example

```
artisan:
    php artisan custom:command2 --arg='myarg'
```

And then your rule for `buidl2` will like

```
build2: artisan dependencies gulp
```